# How to integrate quick books online with qv rest connector?

Tags: oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qlikview

[qv-rest-connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhoKT.png)Hey everyone am trying to integrate qlikview desktop application with quickbooks online using qbo v3 api together with qv rest connector and am having a problem with authorization. Any help highly appreciated

Getting the correct values to enter in the rest connector

Comment: Specifically WHAT authentication problem are you having? What does your code look like?

Comment: check the edited version

Comment: What the heck is the "qb rest connector"? A Google search turns up zero results. Specifically what values are you trying to enter?